# javascript callback in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

An API call

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://api.ipayy.com/v001/c/dc/getjsbykey?gh="xyz">
</script>
```

returns

```
window.onload = function() {
    callback_fn.call(new Object(), false);
}
```

This works perfectly fine with browser.

But the same doesn't work with Phonegap, the callback function isn't executed in Javascript in Phonegap

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script>
     function callback_fn() {
      navigator.notification.alert("new func");
      for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        alert(arguments[i]);
            }
        }
  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.ipayy.com/v001/c/dc/getjsbykey?gh="+window.Encryption.encrypt()"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any equivalent of the following in Phonegap, which will call the function `callback_fn()`?

```
window.onload = function() {
        callback_fn.call(new Object(), false);
}
```

Comment: And your question is? So far you have only reported that something does not work, which per-se is not automatically a programming question. For example, this sounds more like a support request with the Phonegap software. Did you contact Phonegap support and discussed the issue with the vendor?

Comment: I meant to say what format should the api return in order to call the function in the script

Comment: So do you experience that `window.onload` is not invoked in Phonegap probably?

Comment: Well find out so if or if not. Do some logging or reporting, find out the exact cause. That will help you to formulate a better question and to probably already find the solution.

Comment: window.onload() works fine, but somehow <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://api.ipayy.com/v001/c/dc/getjsbykey?gh="xyz">
</script> doesn't return anything to the index.html in android..Besides it does return the above said response in browser

Comment: Then this is probably due to access rights. Perhaps some security feature in the browser prevents to load the linked script? Maybe some cross-domain policy or similiar? Probably it requires HTTPS? Something in that direction is probably that. Maybe you have some development logging with that browser that can highlight such issues?

Comment: Hi @hakre, thanks for keeping track of that.Actually the javascript function is getting called back when I remove the the arguments as window.onload = function() {
        callback_fn.call(); then the function back in my script is getting called. but when I put in the parameters again, then it shows : E/Web Console(12355): Uncaught ReferenceError: callback_fn is not defined at http://103.13.97.143/test/testJs.js:2
}